# Use results of a mySQL SELECT as input of a MATCH AGAINST natural language query

Tags: mysql, nlp, match-against, against

I need to make a research by natural language on a mySQL table field taking as input the values of another table field. I tried something similar but, as I suspected, it was not correct:

```
    SELECT id, name, MATCH(name), 
    AGAINST 
      (
        SELECT name
        FROM table2
      ) AS score
    FROM table1
    WHERE MATCH(name), 
    AGAINST 
      (
        SELECT name
        FROM table2
      )
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE 1**

I followed the kind example here below but i got the error "#1064 - SQL query syntax error near 'tb2". I cannot see this syntax error. Here the code I am testing:

```
SELECT name, MATCH(name) AGAINST 
(

    (SELECT name
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT name 
            FROM active_ingredients

        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT active_ingredients.name as name
        FROM active_ingredients
        INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name

    ) tbl
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    ORDER BY name) tb2 

) AS score
FROM 
(
    
    SELECT alias_name as name
    FROM temp_active_ingredients_aliases
    


) 
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST 
(

    (SELECT name
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT name 
            FROM active_ingredients

        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT active_ingredients.name as name
        FROM active_ingredients
        INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name

    ) tb3
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    ORDER BY name) tb4

)
```

The inner queries return the list of active_ingredients.name that do not exactly match at least one of the temp_active_ingredients_alieases.alias_name fields. So that I then try a match of the not exactly matching name(s) with the alias_name(s) by natural language FULLTEXT research. To be noted that the following inner queries are working properly:

```
    SELECT name
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT name 
            FROM active_ingredients

        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT active_ingredients.name as name
        FROM active_ingredients
        INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name

    ) tbl
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    ORDER BY name
```

I am quite sure that the syntax error is very stupid, but i cannot see it.

**UPDATE 2**

Here the links to the code for generating the two tables (schema and some data)

- https://www.dropbox.com/s/81ks3707dve95r9/active_ingredients%20%281%29.sql?dl=0
- https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pph04dmfpdkksh/temp_active_ingredients_aliases%20%283%29.sql?dl=0

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yiu were almost there

To explain a bit further.

1. You put after the match(name) a comma that is wrong at that position.
2. GROUP_CONCAT is there because MySQL expects there a list of words and this was the easiest way to achieve that, for further information about FulltextaSearch and optimization see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) As you see in the example a space as separator doesn't change anything
3. IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE was only a assumption of mine as you wrote *research by natural language* all other options a also in that link explained

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
> (id int,
> name text,
> FULLTEXT(name))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTo table1 VALUES(1,'text1')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table2
> (id int,
> name text)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1,'text1'),(2,'text2')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.id, t1.name, MATCH(t1.name) 
> AGAINST 
>   (
>     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name)
>     FROM table2) IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
>   ) AS score
> FROM table1 t1 
> WHERE MATCH(t1.name) 
> AGAINST 
>   (
>     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name)
>     FROM table2) IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
>   )
> ```

> ```
> id | name  |                      score
> -: | :---- | -------------------------:
>  1 | text1 | 0.000000001885928302414186
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.id, t1.name, MATCH(t1.name) 
> AGAINST 
>   (
>     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ')
>     FROM table2) IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
>   ) AS score
> FROM table1 t1 
> WHERE MATCH(t1.name) 
> AGAINST 
>   (
>     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ')
>     FROM table2) IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
>   )
> ```

> ```
> id | name  |                      score
> -: | :---- | -------------------------:
>  1 | text1 | 0.000000001885928302414186
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd34d841b4d9751f28c8da27b7de42fe)*

I corrected your mistakes

```
SELECT 
    name,
    MATCH (name) AGAINST ((SELECT 
            name
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                name
            FROM
                active_ingredients UNION ALL SELECT 
                active_ingredients.name AS name
            FROM
                active_ingredients
            INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name) tbl
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        ORDER BY name) ) AS score
FROM
    (SELECT 
        alias_name AS name
    FROM
        temp_active_ingredients_aliases) db2
WHERE
    MATCH (name) AGAINST ((SELECT 
            name
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                name
            FROM
                active_ingredients UNION ALL SELECT 
                active_ingredients.name AS name
            FROM
                active_ingredients
            INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name) tb3
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        ORDER BY name) )
```

Without proper datqa, i can not test it,  in can only remove syntax error

```
SELECT 
    name,
    MATCH (name) AGAINST ((    SELECT name
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT name 
            FROM active_ingredients

        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT active_ingredients.name as name
        FROM active_ingredients
        INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name

    ) tbl
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    ORDER BY name) ) AS score
FROM
    (SELECT 
        alias_name AS name
    FROM
        temp_active_ingredients_aliases) db2
WHERE
    MATCH (name) AGAINST ((    SELECT name
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT name 
            FROM active_ingredients

        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT active_ingredients.name as name
        FROM active_ingredients
        INNER JOIN temp_active_ingredients_aliases ON temp_active_ingredients_aliases.alias_name = active_ingredients.name

    ) tbl
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    ORDER BY name) )
```

Comment: thank you very much. Could you give us few tips for interpretation? You added the clause IN NATURAL LANGUAGE maybe forcing the result to be indexed as NUTARAL LANGUAGE type, irhgt? HOw about GROUP_CONCAT(...) meening and need? Thanks again

Comment: yes sure thank you so much, I was just asking because I found the documentation about GROUP_CONCAT a little bit cryptic and still I have not understood completely its meaning and need.

Comment: You have a number of rows in my exampke 2 but the match needs a string there if all values that is why there is es as groupconcat

Comment: thank you again I tried to adapt your concept on my case, but maybe I am wronging something of very stupid so that i got a syntax error. I added the code I am using in the original question text as UPDATE 1

Comment: this basically anew query, as you should have accepted it. I still think it must be a GEOUP_CONCAT and i still think a NAtural language mode is correct , but when you run your query against your database, we ill see

Comment: no the correct inner query must have the UNION instruction, it's logic work with the UNION. Anyway if you take them away you get a "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" error. If I use the original "inner" query apart from the natural lenguage search it works properly.

Comment: i need proper data to test such query more complicated it  gets make a dbfiddle

Comment: dear nbk i update the question with the links to two sql files for creating the two tables (schema and some data)

Comment: Sometimes i ask myself,why you make complicated queries, if you noz experience with it see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c5bc00a36c398a92962c4ee5aea8e11 i had to change the dates 0000-00-00 00:00:00 becauethe website doesn't like that, and next time make directly a dbfiddle

Comment: thank you nbk for your valuable support. The reason behind the why is the "need" (the query is needed in even a more complex context) and the reason behind the writing here is because as you noted I have a lack of experience that is the reason to be of StackOverflow help people who have to learn. Thank you again. (also for letting me be aware of dbfiddle for which I still have not confidence, i tried to load the creation queries there but got stuked; I will try to learn using this tool for sure).

Comment: you are welcome, what you are trying is very advanced and it needs a lot if knowledge how sql ans mysql work.s. dbfiddle is need whn you want toshow someone your proolem or try somethink that will not work at your home computer. mysql workbench shows you all syntax error, even whebn when does not show the exact point, but at least you know that there is still work to be done